# Url won't change when i click on submit in java

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

Hi i am trying to create a web application in java for the first time and i have a folder named securearea and in it i have a .jsp named AddPublication which i a form in with two textboxes and a submit button.

```
<form method="post" action="AddNewPublication">
        Publication Name: <input type="text" name="publicationname" id="publicationname"/>
        <br>
        Publication URL: <input type="text" name="publicationname" id="publicationurl"/>
        <br>
        <input type ="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

before i submit the url is http://localhost:8080/WebJavaAssignment/SecureArea/AddPublication.jsp which is correct as AddPublication is in the SecureArea folder but when i click submit the url changes http://localhost:8080/WebJavaAssignment/SecureArea/AddNewPublication,
AddNewPublication is a servlet i have but it is not located in SecureArea therefore i recieve an Http 404 error when i click on submit. My question is How can i make it that when i click on that submit button the SecureArea/ goes away? thanks.

Comment: The URL is taken from the `action` property on your `form`. You could use `../AddNewPublication` for example. But shouldn't the servlet also be available in the "secure area"?

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help. it is available to run in the secure area what was happening is that i did not include ../ in the action so the url was not changing properly thanks again